# Inventory Program in C. Need help on how to delete an item from inventory

Tags: c, visual-c++, inventory

This is a program that holds inventory. The program displays a menu of options. Everything else works perfect except the delete an entry function. I do not know how to make it delete a function. I put a variable to find the location but i really have no idea how. I enter the item name to be deleted and then i enter display entry and it goes into an infinite mess. Someone help me on how to make it select an item and delete it from the inventory.
It is used in Visual Studios 2010, Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 25
#define MAX 100

  typedef struct {
    char item[SIZE]; //item for the company
    char company[SIZE]; //company that sells the item
    int intStock; //how many of the item are instock
    char lastShipDate[SIZE]; //last ship date of that item
    double cost; //cost to make the item
    double price; //price of the item 
    } gaming;

//prompts the user to get a selection
int Menu(void);

//display the options to the user
void DisplayOptions(void);

//display some entries for inventory
void HardCodeEntries(gaming entry[],int *size);

//function to add a new entry to the inventory
void AddNewEntry(gaming entry[], int *size);

//function to delete a selected entry from inventory
void Delete(gaming entry[], int *size, int location);

//display the current inventory to screen
void Display(gaming entry[], int size);

//save the current inventory to file
void SaveInventory(gaming br[], int *size);

//clears out the entire inventory
void Clear(int *size);

//load the inventory from the file that is being saved
void LoadSalesRecords(gaming br[], int *size);

//find location of entry that is going to be edited or deleted
int FindLocation(gaming entry[], int size);

//display the options for editing an entry
int EditMenuOptions(void);

//function to edit selected entry
void Edit(gaming entry[], int location);

int main()
{
    int selection;
    gaming entry [150];
    int size=0;
    char trash;
    int choice;
    int location;

    //display size of inventory before and after
    printf("\nSIZE before: %d", size);
    HardCodeEntries(entry, &size);
    printf("\nSIZE after: %d\n\n", size);

    DisplayOptions();

    selection= Menu();

    while(selection != 8)
    {
          if (selection==1)
          { 
              printf("ADD ENTRIES\n\n");
              //display size of inventory before adding entries
              printf("\nSIZE BEFORE ADDING: %d\n", size);

              AddNewEntry(entry, &size);

              //display size of inventory after adding entries
              printf("\nSIZE AFTER ADDING: %d\n", size);
          }
          else if(selection==2)
          {
              printf("DELETE\n\n");
              //get location of entry to be deleted

              location = FindLocation(entry,size);
              printf("\nLOCATION: %d\n", location);

              Delete(entry, &size, location);
          }
          else if(selection==3)
          {
              printf("EDIT\n\n");

              //get the location of entry to be edited
              location = FindLocation(entry, size);

              printf("\nLOCATION: %d\n", location);
              Edit(entry, location);
          }
          else if(selection==4)
          {
              printf("DISPLAY OF INVENTORY\n\n");
              Display(entry, size);
          }
          else if(selection==5)
          {
              printf("SAVING CURRENT INVENTORY TO FILE\n\n");
              SaveInventory(entry, &size);
              //saves to file
          }
          else if(selection==6)
          {
              printf("CLEARING ENTIRE DATA\n\n");
              Clear(&size);
          }
          else if(selection==7)
          {
              printf("LOADING SALES RECORDS FROM FILE\n\n");
              LoadSalesRecords(entry, &size);
          }
          else
          {
              printf("COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED\n\n");
          }

          printf("\n\n");
          DisplayOptions();

          //clears buffer
          scanf("%c", &trash);

          selection = Menu();
    }

    if (selection==8)
    {
        printf("\nHAVE A NICE DAY!!!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

//display the options to the user
void DisplayOptions(void)
{
    printf("HELLO, WELCOME TO THE INVENTORY PROGRAM.\n");
    printf("THIS PROGRAM HOLDS INVENORY FOR ELECTRONICS COMPANIES ALONG WITH THEIR ITEMS, COST TO PRODUCE, PRICE,\n");
    printf("LAST SHIP DATE AND NUMBER IN STOCK\n");
    printf("THERE ARE COMPANIES IN THE INVENTORY ALREADY\n");
    printf("*********************************************\n\n");
    printf("HERE ARE YOUR OPTIONS\n");
    printf("1--ADD A NEW ENTRY\n");
    printf("2--DELETE AN ENTRY\n");
    printf("3--EDIT AN ENTRY\n");
    printf("4--DISPLAY THE INVENTORY\n");
    printf("5--SAVE CURRENT INVENTORY TO FILE\n");
    printf("6--CLEAR THE ENTIRE INVENTORY\n");
    printf("7--LOAD SALES RECORD FROM FILE\n");
    printf("8--QUIT\n");
}

//prompts the user to get a selection
int Menu(void)
{
    int selection;
    printf("\nENTER SELECTION: ");
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    return selection;
}

//display some entries for inventory
void HardCodeEntries(gaming entry[], int *size)
{
    strcpy(entry[0].item,"Xbox360");
    strcpy(entry[0].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[0].cost=200.00;
    strcpy(entry[0].company,"Microsoft");
    entry[0].price=300.0;
    entry[0].intStock=150;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[1].item,"PlayStation3");
    strcpy(entry[1].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[1].cost=200.00;
    strcpy(entry[1].company,"Sony");
    entry[1].price=450.00;
    entry[1].intStock=100;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[2].item,"XboxController");
    strcpy(entry[2].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[2].cost=25.00;
    strcpy(entry[2].company,"Microsoft");
    entry[2].price=50.00;
    entry[2].intStock=50;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[3].item,"PS3Controller");
    strcpy(entry[3].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[3].cost=30.00;
    strcpy(entry[3].company,"Sony");
    entry[3].price=45.00;
    entry[3].intStock=50;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[4].item,"Wii");
    strcpy(entry[4].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[4].cost=100.00;
    strcpy(entry[4].company,"Nintendo");
    entry[4].price=200.00;
    entry[4].intStock=150;

    *size = *size + 1;

}

//function to add a new enty to the inventory
void AddNewEntry(gaming entry[], int *size)
{
    printf("\nENTER ITEM:\t\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].item);

    printf("ENTER SHIP DATE:\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].lastShipDate);

    printf("ENTER COST TO MAKE:\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &entry[*size].cost);

    printf("ENTER COMPANY:\t\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].company);

    printf("ENTER PRICE:\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &entry[*size].price);

    printf("ENTER NUMBER IN STOCK:\t");
    scanf("%d", &entry[*size].intStock);

    *size = *size + 1;
}

//function to delete a selected entry from inventory
void Delete(gaming entry[], int *size, int location)
{
    entry[location] = entry[*size - 1];
    *size = *size - 1;
}

//display the current inventory onto the screen
void Display(gaming entry[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("ITEM:\t\t %s\n", entry[i].item);
        printf("LAST SHIP DATE:\t %s\n", entry[i].lastShipDate);
        printf("COST:\t\t %4.2f\n",entry[i].cost);
        printf("COMPANY:\t %s\n", entry[i].company);
        printf("PRICE:\t\t %4.2f\n", entry[i].price);
        printf("IN STOCK:\t %d\n", entry[i].intStock);
    }
}

//save the current inventory to a file
void SaveInventory(gaming br[], int *size)
{
    FILE *outp;

    if((outp = fopen("output.txt","w"))==0)
    {
        printf("\nCANNOT OPEN FILE\n");
        return;
    }

    //connect to the file
    outp= fopen("output.txt","w");

    fprintf(outp,"%d", *size);
    fwrite(br, sizeof(gaming),*size,outp);

    //close file pointer
    fclose(outp);
}

//clears out the entire inventory
void Clear(int *size)
{
    *size = 0;
}

//load the inventory from the file that is being saved
void LoadSalesRecords(gaming br[], int *size)
{
    FILE * inp;

    if((inp = fopen("output.txt","r"))==0)
    {
        printf("CANNOT OPEN FILE\n");
        return;
    }
    //connect to file
    inp = fopen("output.txt","r");

    fscanf(inp,"%d",size);
    fread(br, sizeof(gaming),*size,inp);

    //close file pointer
    fclose(inp);
}

//find location of entry that is going to be edited or deleted
int FindLocation(gaming entry[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int length;
    char userItem[SIZE];

    //enter the item to delete
    printf("ENTER ITEM TO EDIT OR DELETE: ");
    scanf("%s", userItem);
    length = strlen(userItem);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        userItem[i] = toupper(userItem[i]);
    }
    printf("\nYOUR BRAND IN UPPER CASE IS:  %s\n", userItem);

    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(entry[j].item,userItem)==0)
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//function to edit a selected entry
void Edit(gaming entry[], int location)
{
    int choice;

    choice = EditMenuOptions();

    if(choice==1)
    {
        printf("\nENTER NEW ITEM: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].item);
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        printf("\nENTER SHIP DATE: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].lastShipDate);
    }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        printf("\nENTER COST TO MAKE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].cost);
    }
    else if(choice==4)
    {
        printf("\nENTER COMPANY: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].company);
    }
    else if (choice==5)
    {
        printf("\nENTER PRICE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].price);
    }
    else if (choice==6)
    {
        printf("\nENTER HOW MANY IN STOCK: ");
        scanf("%d", &entry[location].intStock);
    }
    else if (choice==7)
    {

        printf("\nENTER NEW ITEM: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].item);
        printf("\nENTER SHIP DATE: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].lastShipDate);
        printf("\nENTER COST TO MAKE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].cost);
        printf("\nENTER COMPANY: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].company);
        printf("\nENTER PRICE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].price);
        printf("\nENTER HOW MANY IN STOCK: ");
        scanf("%d", &entry[location].intStock);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Entry");
    }
}

//display the options for edditing an entry
int EditMenuOptions(void)
{
    int choice;

    printf("\nENTER 1 TO EDIT ITEM\n");
    printf("ENTER 2 TO EDIT DATE\n");
    printf("ENTER 3 TO EDIT COST\n");
    printf("ENTER 4 TO EDIT COMPANY\n");
    printf("ENTER 5 TO EDIT PRICE\n");
    printf("ENTER 6 TO EDIT NUMBERS IN STOCK\n");
    printf("ENTER 7 TO EDIT ALL DATA\n");
    printf("\nENTER SELECTION: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: I want to know what i need to add to be able to select the inventory i want to delete

Comment: Tip: Use switch(selection) { case 1: (instructions) break; case 2: (instructions) break; ... } construction instead of multiple else ifs, the code will be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Following your coding style, although it should improve:

```
void remove_item(gaming entry[], int *size, int item) {
    memcpy(&entry[item], &entry[*size], sizeof(entry[0]));
    *size = *size - 1;
}
```

This code will override the desired entry (at index `item`) and decrease the last index (`size`) by one.

Comment: how do i put this into the program? I already have a delete function. I added what you put and when it asks for an item, i enter the item name and it just deletes everything

Comment: You already know how to read input (scanf...) use it to get the index to delete.

Comment: Without changing anything, can you make the Findlocation entry work?

Comment: I have a function that finds the location. But i just dont know what to type in. When it asks to enter an item or entry to delete . it gives back the location always as -1. and doesent delete anything

Comment: I don't want to ruin the whole assignment for you :), but for some reason you make the user input upper case, while you don't do it when you add an item, so strcmp fails...

Comment: You might consider a slight modification to your load and save inventory functions. You don't need two fopen() calls. If the first fopen() succeeds the code in the if() block isn't executed and will continue on with an open FIILE * after the if() block. No need to reopen the file.