# Need help to deleting and editing an item in inventory

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inventory Program in C. Need help on how to delete an item from inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286643/inventory-program-in-c-need-help-on-how-to-delete-an-item-from-inventory)

This is a program that holds inventory and displays a menu with options.

Everything else works perfect except the delete and edit entry inventory item. I do not know how to make it delete an item and the entire data it has. I created a function called `FindLocation` to find the location of the entry in the array:

- I enter the item name to be deleted and then I enter display entry and it goes into an infinite mess.
- When you want to delete an item or edit it, it asks for an item or entry.
- I don't know what to enter to make it find the item or (location) of the item.
- Run the program and diplay the inventory, then try to delete an entry, then display the inventory again. You will see the mess im talking about.

Can someone help me fix the `FindLocation` to know what to enter and then be able to  delete an item in the inventory. It is when you select to delete an item in the inventory, that I do not know what to input. It asks:

> ENTER AN ITEM OR ENTRY TO DELETE:

I enter `Xbox360` for example... and it gives back a `-1` and that's it. I select display inventory to see if the item was deleted and it goes into an infinite mess. If you could please add or edit this code and explain to me what you added. That would be great. Thanks, you guys are the best.

All this is developed with Visual Studio 2010. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 25
#define MAX 100

  typedef struct {
    char item[SIZE]; //item for the company
    char company[SIZE]; //company that sells the item
    int intStock; //how many of the item are instock
    char lastShipDate[SIZE]; //last ship date of that item
    double cost; //cost to make the item
    double price; //price of the item 
    } gaming;

//prompts the user to get a selection
int Menu(void);

//display the options to the user
void DisplayOptions(void);

//display some entries for inventory
void HardCodeEntries(gaming entry[],int *size);

//function to add a new entry to the inventory
void AddNewEntry(gaming entry[], int *size);

//function to delete a selected entry from inventory
void Delete(gaming entry[], int *size, int location);

//display the current inventory to screen
void Display(gaming entry[], int size);

//save the current inventory to file
void SaveInventory(gaming br[], int *size);

//clears out the entire inventory
void Clear(int *size);

//load the inventory from the file that is being saved
void LoadSalesRecords(gaming br[], int *size);

//find location of entry that is going to be edited or deleted
int FindLocation(gaming entry[], int size);

//display the options for editing an entry
int EditMenuOptions(void);

//function to edit selected entry
void Edit(gaming entry[], int location);

int main()
{
    int selection;
    gaming entry [150];
    int size=0;
    char trash;
    int choice;
    int location;

    //display size of inventory before and after
    printf("\nSIZE before: %d", size);
    HardCodeEntries(entry, &size);
    printf("\nSIZE after: %d\n\n", size);

    DisplayOptions();

    selection= Menu();

    while(selection != 8)
    {
          if (selection==1)
          { 
              printf("ADD ENTRIES\n\n");
              //display size of inventory before adding entries
              printf("\nSIZE BEFORE ADDING: %d\n", size);

              AddNewEntry(entry, &size);

              //display size of inventory after adding entries
              printf("\nSIZE AFTER ADDING: %d\n", size);
          }
          else if(selection==2)
          {
              printf("DELETE\n\n");
              //get location of entry to be deleted

              location = FindLocation(entry,size);
              printf("\nLOCATION: %d\n", location);

              Delete(entry, &size, location);
          }
          else if(selection==3)
          {
              printf("EDIT\n\n");

              //get the location of entry to be edited
              location = FindLocation(entry, size);

              printf("\nLOCATION: %d\n", location);
              Edit(entry, location);
          }
          else if(selection==4)
          {
              printf("DISPLAY OF INVENTORY\n\n");
              Display(entry, size);
          }
          else if(selection==5)
          {
              printf("SAVING CURRENT INVENTORY TO FILE\n\n");
              SaveInventory(entry, &size);
              //saves to file
          }
          else if(selection==6)
          {
              printf("CLEARING ENTIRE DATA\n\n");
              Clear(&size);
          }
          else if(selection==7)
          {
              printf("LOADING SALES RECORDS FROM FILE\n\n");
              LoadSalesRecords(entry, &size);
          }
          else
          {
              printf("COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED\n\n");
          }

          printf("\n\n");
          DisplayOptions();

          //clears buffer
          scanf("%c", &trash);

          selection = Menu();
    }

    if (selection==8)
    {
        printf("\nHAVE A NICE DAY!!!\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

//display the options to the user
void DisplayOptions(void)
{
    printf("HELLO, WELCOME TO THE INVENTORY PROGRAM.\n");
    printf("THIS PROGRAM HOLDS INVENORY FOR ELECTRONICS COMPANIES ALONG WITH THEIR ITEMS, COST TO PRODUCE, PRICE,\n");
    printf("LAST SHIP DATE AND NUMBER IN STOCK\n");
    printf("THERE ARE COMPANIES IN THE INVENTORY ALREADY\n");
    printf("*********************************************\n\n");
    printf("HERE ARE YOUR OPTIONS\n");
    printf("1--ADD A NEW ENTRY\n");
    printf("2--DELETE AN ENTRY\n");
    printf("3--EDIT AN ENTRY\n");
    printf("4--DISPLAY THE INVENTORY\n");
    printf("5--SAVE CURRENT INVENTORY TO FILE\n");
    printf("6--CLEAR THE ENTIRE INVENTORY\n");
    printf("7--LOAD SALES RECORD FROM FILE\n");
    printf("8--QUIT\n");
}

//prompts the user to get a selection
int Menu(void)
{
    int selection;
    printf("\nENTER SELECTION: ");
    scanf("%d", &selection);

    return selection;
}

//display some entries for inventory
void HardCodeEntries(gaming entry[], int *size)
{
    strcpy(entry[0].item,"Xbox360");
    strcpy(entry[0].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[0].cost=200.00;
    strcpy(entry[0].company,"Microsoft");
    entry[0].price=300.0;
    entry[0].intStock=150;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[1].item,"PlayStation3");
    strcpy(entry[1].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[1].cost=200.00;
    strcpy(entry[1].company,"Sony");
    entry[1].price=450.00;
    entry[1].intStock=100;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[2].item,"XboxController");
    strcpy(entry[2].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[2].cost=25.00;
    strcpy(entry[2].company,"Microsoft");
    entry[2].price=50.00;
    entry[2].intStock=50;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[3].item,"PS3Controller");
    strcpy(entry[3].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[3].cost=30.00;
    strcpy(entry[3].company,"Sony");
    entry[3].price=45.00;
    entry[3].intStock=50;

    *size = *size + 1;

    strcpy(entry[4].item,"Wii");
    strcpy(entry[4].lastShipDate,"04/10/12");
    entry[4].cost=100.00;
    strcpy(entry[4].company,"Nintendo");
    entry[4].price=200.00;
    entry[4].intStock=150;

    *size = *size + 1;

}

//function to add a new enty to the inventory
void AddNewEntry(gaming entry[], int *size)
{
    printf("\nENTER ITEM:\t\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].item);

    printf("ENTER SHIP DATE:\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].lastShipDate);

    printf("ENTER COST TO MAKE:\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &entry[*size].cost);

    printf("ENTER COMPANY:\t\t");
    scanf("%s", entry[*size].company);

    printf("ENTER PRICE:\t\t");
    scanf("%lf", &entry[*size].price);

    printf("ENTER NUMBER IN STOCK:\t");
    scanf("%d", &entry[*size].intStock);

    *size = *size + 1;
}

//function to delete a selected entry from inventory
void Delete(gaming entry[], int *size, int location)
{
    entry[location] = entry[*size - 1];
    *size = *size - 1;
}

//display the current inventory onto the screen
void Display(gaming entry[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("ITEM:\t\t %s\n", entry[i].item);
        printf("LAST SHIP DATE:\t %s\n", entry[i].lastShipDate);
        printf("COST:\t\t %4.2f\n",entry[i].cost);
        printf("COMPANY:\t %s\n", entry[i].company);
        printf("PRICE:\t\t %4.2f\n", entry[i].price);
        printf("IN STOCK:\t %d\n", entry[i].intStock);
    }
}

//save the current inventory to a file
void SaveInventory(gaming br[], int *size)
{
    FILE *outp;

    if((outp = fopen("output.txt","w"))==0)
    {
        printf("\nCANNOT OPEN FILE\n");
        return;
    }

    //connect to the file
    outp= fopen("output.txt","w");

    fprintf(outp,"%d", *size);
    fwrite(br, sizeof(gaming),*size,outp);

    //close file pointer
    fclose(outp);
}

//clears out the entire inventory
void Clear(int *size)
{
    *size = 0;
}

//load the inventory from the file that is being saved
void LoadSalesRecords(gaming br[], int *size)
{
    FILE * inp;

    if((inp = fopen("output.txt","r"))==0)
    {
        printf("CANNOT OPEN FILE\n");
        return;
    }
    //connect to file
    inp = fopen("output.txt","r");

    fscanf(inp,"%d",size);
    fread(br, sizeof(gaming),*size,inp);

    //close file pointer
    fclose(inp);
}

//find location of entry that is going to be edited or deleted
int FindLocation(gaming entry[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int length;
    char userItem[SIZE];

    //enter the item to delete
    printf("ENTER ITEM TO EDIT OR DELETE: ");
    scanf("%s", userItem);
    length = strlen(userItem);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        userItem[i] = toupper(userItem[i]);
    }
    printf("\nYOUR BRAND IN UPPER CASE IS:  %s\n", userItem);

    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(entry[j].item,userItem)==0)
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

//function to edit a selected entry
void Edit(gaming entry[], int location)
{
    int choice;

    choice = EditMenuOptions();

    if(choice==1)
    {
        printf("\nENTER NEW ITEM: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].item);
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        printf("\nENTER SHIP DATE: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].lastShipDate);
    }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        printf("\nENTER COST TO MAKE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].cost);
    }
    else if(choice==4)
    {
        printf("\nENTER COMPANY: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].company);
    }
    else if (choice==5)
    {
        printf("\nENTER PRICE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].price);
    }
    else if (choice==6)
    {
        printf("\nENTER HOW MANY IN STOCK: ");
        scanf("%d", &entry[location].intStock);
    }
    else if (choice==7)
    {

        printf("\nENTER NEW ITEM: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].item);
        printf("\nENTER SHIP DATE: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].lastShipDate);
        printf("\nENTER COST TO MAKE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].cost);
        printf("\nENTER COMPANY: ");
        scanf("%s", &entry[location].company);
        printf("\nENTER PRICE: ");
        scanf("%lf", &entry[location].price);
        printf("\nENTER HOW MANY IN STOCK: ");
        scanf("%d", &entry[location].intStock);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Entry");
    }
}

//display the options for edditing an entry
int EditMenuOptions(void)
{
    int choice;

    printf("\nENTER 1 TO EDIT ITEM\n");
    printf("ENTER 2 TO EDIT DATE\n");
    printf("ENTER 3 TO EDIT COST\n");
    printf("ENTER 4 TO EDIT COMPANY\n");
    printf("ENTER 5 TO EDIT PRICE\n");
    printf("ENTER 6 TO EDIT NUMBERS IN STOCK\n");
    printf("ENTER 7 TO EDIT ALL DATA\n");
    printf("\nENTER SELECTION: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: FYI, instead of having an if statement with so many 'else if' statements, why not go with a switch?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What is the significance of '[FIXED]' in the title?  It would normally mean that there is no problem left to resolve; is that what you mean?

Comment: For the third time - remove the following lines: `for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        userItem[i] = toupper(userItem[i]);
    }
    printf("\nYOUR BRAND IN UPPER CASE IS:  %s\n", userItem);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286643/inventory-program-in-c-need-help-on-how-to-delete-an-item-from-inventory/10286696#10286696

Comment: And if you don't mind - don't post the question over and over again. You can simply edit your previous.

Comment: Fixed it Binyamin. Thanks to you. Its just that it has to be entered in uppercase

Comment: If so, make it upper case when you add to the inventory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Re. Your deleted question: For getGrades, you need to put your scanf into a loop that checks if a negative number has been entered and reprompts if not. Each non-negative grade that is entered needs to be stored somehow - an array seems easiest  Once a negative number is entered, you need to loop through your array and calculate the average.

For Get_Info, you are only supposed to pass one argument into the function, namely a pointer to your structure. You'll need to set up the pointer and then pass it in. The function itself is supposed to get data from the user (not display it, as you have done). So you'll need to use scanf again but store the data using the pointer that was just passed.

Hope that gets you going in the right direction :) Sorry you got so heckled.